# How to load data in CSV file into Python script for probability analysis?

Tags: python, linux, csv, sensors

I have a Python script which I'm using to simulate an IoT environment. The script has static values and is basic (unlike more advanced simulators out there like Pymote, NS etc.). I later plan to add a Lightweight Neural Network into the script for anomaly detection, but this is in the future. 
I have a CSV file (node.csv) with the following data -

```
1.0,0.5,0.2
0.6,1.0,0.2
0.3,0.4,1.0
```

To be precise, these are probabilities of "rate of success" or Success Rate of a "message" being passed from Node 0 to Node 1,2 , Node 1 to Node 2,0 etc.
The code is as follows -

```
import numpy as np

# dict <epoch, dict <node id, value>>
# change later to read from file instead
sensor_values = {0: {0: 12.0, 1: 15.0, 2: 20.0},
                 1: {0: 12.5, 1: 18.0, 2: np.nan},
                 2: {0: 11.0, 1: np.nan, 2: 20.0},
                 3: {0: 10.0, 1: 150.0, 2: 28.0},
                 4: {0: np.nan, 1: 15.0, 2: 27.0}
                }


# static configuration
max_epoch = 5
node_ids = range(3)
connection_success_rates = [[1.0, 0.5, 0.2],
                            [0.6, 1.0, 0.2],
                            [0.3, 0.4, 1.0]]  # change later to read from 
                                              # file instead

# simulation global variables
nodes_memory = None  # dict <node_id, dict <key, value>>
successful_communications = None
failed_communications = None


# initialize simulation global variables
def init():
    global nodes_memory
    nodes_memory = dict()
    for node_id in node_ids:
        nodes_memory[node_id] = dict()
    global successful_communications
    global failed_communications
    successful_communications, failed_communications = 0, 0


def print_node_memory(node_id):
    print 'Memory content of node %d' % node_id
    for key in nodes_memory[node_id]:
        print 'Key={%s}, value={%s}' % (key, nodes_memory[node_id][key])

# here we could print some extra stats, like the size of used memory...


def print_communication_stats():
    print '--- Communication stats ---'
    print 'successful communications: %d' % successful_communications
    print 'failed communications: %d' % failed_communications
    print 'total communications: %d' % (successful_communications + 
                                         failed_communications)


# send <key, value> from sender to receiver according to connection success 
# rates
def send_value(sender_id, receiver_id, key, value):
    success_rate = connection_success_rates[sender_id][receiver_id]
    if np.random.rand() < success_rate:
        # communication successful
        # write transmitted value in target node memory
        nodes_memory[receiver_id][key] = value
        global successful_communications
        successful_communications += 1
        return True
    else:
        # communication fails
        global failed_communications
        failed_communications += 1
        return False
    # some energy counter could be added here too


# internal behavior of each node
# (neural networks will added here later)
def run_node(local_id, epoch):

    # send current value to all other nodes
    for target_node_id in node_ids:
        if target_node_id != local_id:
        # this will be adapted later to communicate with neighbor nodes only
            key = 'node=%d, epoch=%d' % (local_id, epoch)
            value = sensor_values[epoch][local_id]
            send_value(local_id, target_node_id, key, value)

    # here we could do some additional stuff

     # for example clean old values (more than 3 epochs) from node memory
    keys_to_remove = []
    for key in nodes_memory[local_id]:
        # parse key to get epoch when the value was written
        # later the values should be encapsulated in objects for convenience
        epoch_received = int(key[key.find('epoch=')+len('epoch='):])
        if epoch - epoch_received > 3:
        # mark for delete as python does not support deleting values while 
        iterating through dict
        # print 'marked old value with key %s from epoch %d for removal' % 
        (key, epoch_received)
            keys_to_remove.append(key)

     for key_to_remove in keys_to_remove:
        print 'removing old value with key %s' % key_to_remove
        nodes_memory[local_id].pop(key_to_remove)
     return 0


def main():
    print 'Simulation example'
    init()

    for epoch in range(max_epoch):
        print '------------- Epoch %d -------------' % epoch
        for node_id in node_ids:
            print '--- Node %d ---' % node_id
            run_node(node_id, epoch)
            print_node_memory(node_id)

    print_communication_stats()

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I hope that the code is clear enough to read, although for sure it needs refinement.
In short, the code runs 5 'epochs' with each Node having its respective success rate with other Nodes. Also, each Node would have a memory which stores 'data' received from other Nodes. (The output will be clear once the code is run)
The problem that I'm facing at the moment is using the `connection_success_rates` from the CSV file into my code. I tried using the following into my original code -

```
import csv # at the very top

f = open('node.csv')
csvfile = csv.readfile(f, delimiter=',')
connection_success_rates = []

for row in csvfile:
    connection_success_rates.append(row)   # Commented the previous 
                           # connection_success_rates section completely
```

But this did not help. Although the code still ran, it completely ignored the CSV file section, hence it could not take in the success rates as it does in the original code. I have tried several other combinations of using the CSV option but nothing helped. (I plan on extending the same with `sensor_values` section as well)
I'm particular in using CSV file format because I will be inserting a Neural Network later as NNs use large datasets from CSV files. Plus I will be using a larger dataset with many number of nodes later in the script, but I first need this simple task running with this simple data.
I humbly request anyone for help. Please correct me if I should make changes in the particular data or in the further definitions of the code itself.
Thank you all in advance.

P.S. - This is my first question on SOF so please go easy on me for any mistakes.

Comment: use pandas: import pandas as pd and then f  = pd.read_csv("node.csv", header=...)

Comment: I just posted an answer. I hope that I understood correctly your question.

Comment: If you can't use pandas for some reason, you can try `line.split(',')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that the connection_success_rates that you manually create is a list so a possible solution could be using pandas as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

connection_success_rates = pd.read_csv("node.csv", header=None)

#convert the dataframe to list
connection_success_rates =connection_success_rates.values.tolist()

print(connection_success_rates)
```

Result:

```
[[1.0, 0.5, 0.2], [0.6, 1.0, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4, 1.0]]
```

So remove this part:

```
import csv 

f = open('node.csv')
csvfile = csv.readfile(f, delimiter=',')
connection_success_rates = []

for row in csvfile:
    connection_success_rates.append(row)
```

and try using the one that I posted above.

Comment: @MFHS  I hope this answers your question

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't need to print the content of the CSV file. I only want the script to take the values in the CSV file and use it in the definition 'send_value' because the object success_rate = connection_success_rates[sender_id][receiver_id] has to take the values from the file and use them as a probability for node to node communication. I hope that when you ran the original code, you would have seen that there are always different values for successful and failed communications. I want the same to happen but with the data from the file and not static. Thank you @bendl

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment, this solution actually helped, I put your code in the wrong place in my script, but it's running successfully now.

Comment: Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: @MFHS  no problem! I am glad that you solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

For for the sake of having a pure python solution to the problem, it can be solved like this:

```
connection_success_rates = []
with open('node.csv') as file:
    connection_success_rates = [line.split(',') for line in file.readlines()]
```